# ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dims, but the arr at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the arr at index 11 has 2 dimension(s)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have array as follows

```py
samples_data = [array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)
 array([ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ..., -0.00020519,
        -0.00019427, -0.00107348], dtype=float32)
 array([ 0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00, ...,
        -8.9004419e-07,  7.3998461e-07, -6.9706215e-07], dtype=float32)
 array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)]
```

And I have a function like this

```py
def generate_segmented_data_1(
    samples_data: np.ndarray, sampling_rate: int = 16000
) -> np.ndarray:

    new_data = []

    for data in samples_data:
        segments = segment_audio(data, sampling_rate=sampling_rate)
        new_data.append(segments)

    new_data = np.array(new_data)

    return np.concatenate(new_data)
```

It shows error like this

```sh
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 11 has 2 dimension(s)
```

And the array at index 0 is like this

```sh
[array([ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ..., -0.00022057,
         0.00013752, -0.00114789], dtype=float32)
 array([-4.3174211e-04, -5.4488028e-04, -1.1238289e-03, ...,
         8.4724619e-05,  3.0450989e-05, -3.9514929e-05], dtype=float32)]
```

then the array at index 11 is like this

```sh
[[3.0856067e-05 3.0295929e-05 3.0955063e-05 ... 8.5010566e-03
  1.3315652e-02 1.5698154e-02]]
```

And then what should I do so all of the segments I produced being concatenated as an array of segments?

Comment: _"This will result (1, 1). But, I want it results (1, ) without flattening it?"_ You can try `squeeze()`, but it's effectively eqivalent to flattening it.

Comment: Which version of numpy are you running? I get a depreciation warning when creating the array `a = np.array([[2], [1,2]])`

Comment: @Olsgaard ```'1.21.5'```

Comment: Why dont you want to flatten it? And how else could this be done except by flatten???

Comment: @GPhilo I don't see if I flatten the array it will solve my problem

Comment: I think I want to reconstruct my question

Comment: The question (you need to figure out for yourself) is **why** segment 11 is 2D. `segment_audio` is likely the culprit, but can't say more without the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do I can get the shape of below array to be 1D instead of 2D?
>
> ```
> b = np.array([[2]])
> b_shape = b.shape
> ```
>
> This will result (1, 1). But, I want it results (1, ) without flattening it?

I suspect the confusion stems from the fact that you chose an example which can be also seen as a scalar, so I'll instead use a different example:

```
b = np.array([[1,2]])
```

now, `b.shape` is `(1,2)`. Removing the first "one" dimension **in any way** (be it `b.flatten()` or `b.squeeze()` or using `b[0]`) all result in the same:

```
assert (b.flatten() == b.squeeze()).all()
assert (b.flatten() == b[0]).all()
```

---

Now, for the real problem: it appears you're trying to concatenate "rows" from "segments", but the "segments" (which I believe from your sample dat are lists of `np.array`s?) are inconsistently formed.

Your sample data is very chaotic: Segments 0-10 seem to be lists of 1D arrays; Segment 11, 18 and 19 are either 2D arrays or lists of lists of floats. This, plus the error code, suggest you have an issue in the data processing of the segments.

Now, to actually concatenate both types of data:

```
new_data = []
for data in samples_data:
    segments = function_a(data)     # it appears this doesn't return consistent data
    segments = np.asarray(segments) # force it to always be an array...
    if segments.ndim > 1:           # ...and append each row
        for row in segments:
            new_data.append(row)
    elif segments.ndim == 1:        # if just one row, append it directly
        new_data.append(segments)
    else:
        # function_a returned an empty list, do nothing
        pass
```

Given the shown data and code, this *should* work (but it's neither efficient, nor tested).

Comment: I reconstructed my question. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: actually this leads to solve my problem, though I have to explore more to my own code. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure I understand what you are trying to do.

```py
b = np.array([[2]])
b.shape
# (1,1)

b = np.array([2])
b.shape
# (1,)
```

For the segment part of the question, it is unclear what your data structure is, but the code example is broken, as you are appending to a list that hasn't been created.

Comment: yes, the ```samples_data``` is numpy array. The dimension is (n, ). And, actually the ```samples_data``` is array of array, like this.
```samples_data = array([array([2,3]), array([1,3,4]), array([1]), ...])```

Comment: I reconstructed my question. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31238847)

Comment: @mylogon It answers the first part of the original question, which was how to make an array of shape `(1,)`. Since answering, the question has been changed.